# Failed to escape double quotes in echo statements

Tags: php

So I wanna display a checkbox associated with the ID of sponsors:

```
echo "<tr>";//line 1
echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">';//line 2
echo '<input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="{$row['sponsors_id']}" />';//line 3
echo '</td>';//line 4
```

Then I got the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in line 3
```

I tried to escape via `\"stuff\"` and `{}`,they both did not work though.

Answer (score 3):

try this for line 3:

```
echo '<input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="'.$row['sponsors_id'].'" />';
```

a single-quoted string isn't parsed for replacement variables, even when delimiting them with { and }.

Comment: For performance - you should use single quotes unless double quotes are necessary. i.e. the string needs to be parsed.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the concatenation dots:

```
echo '<input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="' . $row['sponsors_id'] . '" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the single quote on the line 3, the following piece of code is breaking your syntax:

```
{$row[**'**sponsors_id**'**]}
```

Please, note the single quote between the **.

You should change line 3 in:

```
echo '<input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="' . $row['sponsors_id'] . '" />';//line 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="{$row['sponsors_id']}" />';
```

Single quotes do not parse variables in it.  Try it in double quotes instead:

```
echo "<input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' id='checkbox[]' value='{$row['sponsors_id']}' />";
```